# upload a file to sandbox from my application

Tags: swift, soap, attachment

I am very new to iOS, I don't know how to upload a local file from my application to sandbox document library. 
I got one way in objC, but I am unable to perform it in swift.

```
NSString *str=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:str];
NSString *base64String = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"%@", base64String);
```

SoapMessage:

```
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><AddAttachment xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'><listName>string</listName><listItemID>string</listItemID><fileName>File</fileName><attachment>base64String</attachment></AddAttachment>/soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advnace.